# np.dot mistakenly changed from matrix multiplication to element wise product

Tags: python

```
with tf.Session() as test:
    A = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], shape=[2, 3])
    print(A.shape)
    print(A.eval())
    G = np.dot(A,A)
    print(G.shape)
    print(G.eval())
```

As showed in the page, in for tensors, the np.dot changed from matrix multiplication to element wise product, but the np.dot never mentioned this. Can anyone help explain why? Thank you very much

[image: result]

Comment: What version of tensorflow and numpy are you using? `np.dot(A, A)` on a rectangular matrix `A` should fail. I cannot reproduce your example. If I try to use tensorflow 1 for your example (which I believe you're using due to the "session"), I get that I cannot convert a symbolic tensor to an array.

Comment: he can do it because, A is a tensor, not numpy array

Comment: np.dot(A,A): <tf.Tensor 'mul_1:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=int32>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For basic algebra, you can't multiple dot product of rectangular matrix `(a x b)` with `(a x b)`. You can only multple it by tranpose. `(a x b)x(a x b).T = (a x b)(b x a) = (a x a)`. Therefore, your `np.dot` is not valid.

However, the reason you can still execute is because your A is a tensor, not a numpy array.

`A <tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=int32>`

Therefore the dot product will turn into mul for tensor

`np.dot(A,A) <tf.Tensor 'mul_1:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=int32>`

Comment: Thanks a lot dtlam! I'm just kind of curious why np.dot will turn into mul for tensor, since it's never mentioned in np.dot dictionary. - it only  mentioned will turn mul for 0/1 D arrays, so I'm quite curious on how can this be..

Comment: be careful with tf and numpy :) have a good journey Fred

Answer (score 0):

`np.dot()` when operating on 2d numpy array produced same result as `np.matmul()`. Since, its same as matmul, it can't multiply rectangular matrix with itself so use transpose as second argument.

As shown below

```
G = np.dot(A,tf.transpose(A))
g2 = np.matmul(A,tf.transpose(A))
print(G.shape)
print(G-g2)
>>> [[0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

What you can do instead is use

```
tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(A, A))
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=91>
```

then you can call `.numpy()` on it to get 91.

But if you want to multiply element-wise then use

```
tf.multiply(A, A)
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [16, 25, 36]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: thanks Ragnar for the reply! it's really helpful and in great detail. :) Yes np.dot cannot multiply rectangular matrix, but I feel quite weird why the np.dot can execute when put tensor inside - like the example I showed, np.dot surprisingly turned into element wise multiply. As I searched in np.dot dictionary, it only mentioned will turn element-wise multiply for 0/1 D arrays but never mention tensors, so I don't know if it's a bug or something that I don't know so raised this question..